# Is piloting a HYDRA Parasit (flying bomb) a suicide mission?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-america-the-first-avenger

HYDRA operatives certainly don't seem to mind [killing themselves](https://www.youtube.com/watch?t=199&v=CEfbnrwva-8&feature=youtu.be) for the greater good, but pilots are expensive to train and wasting them seems like a poor use of time and money.

The Marvel Wiki identifies the Parasit 'flying bomb' as being ["*controlled by a single suicide pilot*"](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/HYDRA_Parasit#:%7E:text=Each%20individual%20bomb%20was%20controlled%20by%20a%20single%20suicide%20pilot.) (presumably similar to the [Fieseler Fi 103R Reichenberg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fieseler_Fi_103R_Reichenberg)), but do we have any definitive evidence that the aim was for them to actually pilot it into their target ***and kill themselves in the process?***

[image]

Answer (score 5):

In this instance the Wiki seems to be incorrect. According to the concept art shown in *[The Art of Captain America: The First Avenger](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/The_Art_of_Captain_America:_The_First_Avenger)*, the intention was to jettison the nosecone (which contains the bomb), allowing the pilot to fly back up to the flying wing and re-dock.

> Again taking his cue from Johnston, [Daniel] Simon said he kept the
> Hydra Drone plane — also known as the “Drehflugler" — as simple as
> possible, without any “fancy gimmicks and shapes. Joe kept mentioning
> 'flying bomb.’ So I turned that problem into the solution: **The front
> is literally the bomb. And once released, the plane has a stubby,
> nose-less appearance."**

---

You can see the characteristic "bomb" shape on this cleaned up image of the final concept.

[image]

and an earlier version with the nosecap removed.

[image]

Comment: They should really have had a small nose of the plane extending into the bomb.

Comment: @OrangeDog - That thing would fall out of the sky with or without a flat nose.

Comment: To comment more on the similarities with Nazi Germany designs, another reference is the [Triebfüglel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Focke-Wulf_Triebfl%C3%BCgel)